# Regular expression to match 25 IP addresses in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I was having issues with a RegEx. Mainly I wanted to create a filter to only find these 25 IP addresses in Google Analytics:

- 216.54.215.0
- 216.54.215.1
- 216.54.215.2
- ...
- 216.54.215.24

I first thought I could use:

```
216\.54\.215\.([0-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-4])
```

[RegEx Test](http://regex101.com/r/qB7lV8)

But as you can see, it's not capturing the second digit of 10-24.

Then I turned on Display Whitespace, and noticed that maybe the RegEx was having a problem with the line breaks. So I attempted to select only a single digit after the last `.` by using `[0-9]` and `$`:

`216\.54\.215\.([0-9]$|[1][0-9]|[2][0-4])` Didn't recognize any of 0-9, which is strange as I thought it would have matched a single digit [0-9] and ends after that i.e. $. Am I wrong to assume this?

So next, I turned on *display whitespace*, and I saw that there were line breaks for each IP address. I don't know why I decided to try word boundary, but I decided to swap out my `$` for `\b`. And what do you know, it worked.

```
216\.54\.215\.([0-9]\b|[1][0-9]|[2][0-4])
```

The definition for word boundary is: Matches, without consuming any characters, immediately between a character matched by `\w` and a character not matched by `\w` (in either order).

Questions:

1. Is this the best way to write the RegEx?
2. Why doesn't the `$` work in my second example?
3. Why does `\b` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
216\.54\.215\.([0-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-4])+
```

The added `+` at the end means

> Matches the previous element one or more times. e.g.
>
> **Pattern**: "be+"
>   **Matches**: "bee" in "been", "be" in "bent"

And even better you can go for

```
216\.54\.215\.([0-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-4]){1,3}
```

then you only will select 3 digits at the end and it eliminates the possibility of the error if the 4th digit is typed in by mistake. (might or might not be useful in your case)

> In general `{ n , m }` matches the previous element at least n times,
>   but no more than m times.
>
> **Pattern** "\d{3,5}" **Matches** "166", "17668" & "19302" in "193024"

And this would be your results. [Results](http://regex101.com/r/qB7lV8)

So the exact solution for your case is to use

```
216\.54\.215\.([0-9]\b|[1][0-9]|[2][0-4]){1,2}\b
```

Which means you want only two digits at the end with is limited to 24 and the boundry finishes there then Regex won't select `216.54.215.24` out of `216.54.215.2411`.

And [this](http://regex101.com/r/sU3jH0) is the final result.

I always keep [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page open as a reference when I am working with Regexs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regex you need:
`^216\.54\.215\.([0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])$`

Answer (score 0):

A regex that should work is:

```
^216\.54\.215\.(1?[0-9]|2[0-4])$
```

Addresses 0-9 are covered by `1?[0-9]`, where the `1?` matches nothing.

Addresses 10-19 are covered by `1?[0-9]`, where the `1?` matches the tens digit.

Addresses 20-24 are covered by `2[0-4]`.